# ¿Cómo salir de While Loop cuando ya no se cumple la condición en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy ejecutando este código sin cerrar la App hasta que el usuario teclea S o s para salir de la App o <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> para salir por completo.
El problema está en que cuando tecleo 1 o 2 se vuelve un ciclo infinito.

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando presione uno de estos números, solo se ejecute una vez sin cerrar la App hasta que otra vez vuelva a ingresar otro número.

Este es mi código de Python

```
import re


def run():
    entrada = None
    print("\nBienvenido al programa de Python")
    print("¿Qué deseas hacer en esta App?")
    while True:
        print(f"\n\nTeclea un número del 1 al 7 o S para salir de la App")
        while not entrada or not re.match(r'[sS1-7]+$', entrada) or len(entrada) > 1:
            entrada = input("Dame un número: ")

        if entrada == "s" or str(entrada) == "S":
            print("\nAdios!\nVuelve pronto".upper())
            break

        elif int(entrada) == 1:
            print(f"Esta es la operación {entrada}")

        elif int(entrada) == 2:
            print(f"Esta es la operación {entrada}")


        print(f"Ejecutaste la operación {entrada}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f"\n\nApp Interrumpida!".upper())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en que al elegir 1 o 2, el programa ya no ingresa al segundo bucle debido a que "entrada" ya tiene un valor. Te recomiendo poner `entrada = None` debajo del primer `while` para refrescar el valor de la entrada.

Answer (score 0):

Primero te pongo mi código y lo vamos comentando.

```
def run():
    print("\nBienvenido al programa de Python")
    while True:

        print("¿Qué deseas hacer en esta App?")
        while True:
            print(f"\n\nTeclea un número del 1 al 7 o S para salir de la App")
            entrada = input("Dame un número: ")
            if entrada.lower() in ['s'] + list(map(str, range(1, 7+1))):
                break

        if entrada.lower() == 's': break
        elif entrada == '1': print(f"Esta es la operación {entrada}")
        elif int(entrada) == '2': print(f"Esta es la operación {entrada}")
        else: print(f"Ejecutaste la operación {entrada}")

run()
```

En otros lenguajes hay una sentencia

```
Do
    ...
 
While(condicion = True)
```

Esto no existe en python pero lo puedes emular con esta sentencia:

```
while True:
    ...
    ...
    if not condicion == True:
        break
```

**Tu problema:**
Comparas el valor de `entrada` con el dato que obtienes anteriormente que ya sabemos que se cumple.

**Como solucionarlo:**

```
Usando tu codigo:
```

```
    print("¿Qué deseas hacer en esta App?")
    while True:
        print(f"\n\nTeclea un número del 1 al 7 o S para salir de la App")
        entrada = input("Dame un número: ")
        while not entrada in ['s'] + list(map(str, range(1,8))):
            entrada = input("Dame un número: ")

        if entrada == "s" or str(entrada) == "S":
            print("\nAdios!\nVuelve pronto".upper())
            break

        elif int(entrada) == 1:
            print(f"Esta es la operación {entrada}")

        elif int(entrada) == 2:
            print(f"Esta es la operación {entrada}")
```

Fijate que antes del `while not` pongo una nueva entrada de datos, y si no corresponde que se repita hasta que sea válida.

** Otra opción**

El código que te ponía al principio emulando un `Do While`